# Find in a string a comma followed by a space and then a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, split

I have a string containing this format

"`Item 1, Item 2, Another Item`, 2004"

I would like to split the string at the , 2004 and format it to display

"`<em>Item 1, Item 2, Another Item</em>`, 2004"

So far I have this

```
          var myString = "";
          var new_html = [];
          var splitstring = this.split(',');
               $.each(splitstring, function (idx) {
                   if (new_html.length == 0) new_html.push('<em>' + splitstring[idx] + '</em>');
                   else new_html.push(splitstring[idx]);
               });
                    myString+=("<span class='line"+index+"'>"+new_html.join(',') + "<br/></span>");
```

This isn't going to work but if someone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Do you want to find out last comma in your string?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no in theory I want the last comma only if it's followed by a date... It might not be possible.

Comment: But how come 2004 is a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this pattern:

```
/, (?=\d)/
```

This will match a comma, followed by a space, but only if it is later followed by a digit.

The `(?=...)` is a lookahead assertion. It ensures that the pattern inside the parentheses appears after the matched substring, but it is not included in the match.

You can simply use this in your split function like this:

```
var splitstring = this.split(/, (?=\d)/);
...
```

---

If you'd like to ensure that it's followed by something that looks like a 4-digit year you could use:

```
/, (?=\d{4})/
```

Or

```
/, (?=(?:19|20)\d\d)/
```

Depending on your exact needs.

Comment: As per the OP `I want the last comma only if it's followed by a date` I know 2004 is not a date

Comment: How would I add this to the split function? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Written multi-line for clarity & explanation inline.

```
var str = "Item 1, Item 2, Another Item, 2004"; 

var arr = str.split(','); //splitting by commas

var num = arr.pop(); //popping the last value '2004'

var result = '<em>'+ arr.join(',') + '</em>' + ',' + num; //joining back again

result: "<em>Item 1, Item 2, Another Item</em>, 2004"
```

if the `num` is an year, you can check as `(num < 2099) && (num > 1990)` (just an example) and use the condition to do specific stuff

Comment: Can you talk me through this - I'll check if it works Thanks!

Comment: Note this will only work if the year appears after the last comma. Given OP's comments I don't think that's desired, but It may be good enough.